# Online recording the president's speech in The Undiscovered Country

Tags: star-trek

Remember when the president of the united federation of planets is giving his speech while the assassin is preparing in his lookout? That speech included something like, "let us redefine progress. Just because we can do a thing doesn't mean we must do that thing..." and it was pretty good. Other than the movie itself, is there a video of that speech? And, was there more to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**; it appears to not have any deleted scenes, or extra recordings of this scene, ive included two scripts, one of which appears to have a few more lines that may not have been in the movie.

> [Camp Khitomer conference hall]
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT: Madam Chancellor, members of the diplomatic
>   corps, ...honoured guests. The United Federation of Planets welcomes
>   you to Camp Khitomer.
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT: Let us redefine progress to mean that just
>   because we can do a thing it does not necessarily follow that we must
>   do that thing.
>
> AZETBUR: Many speculated about my father's motives. There were those who said he was an idealist, others said he had no choice. If Praxis had not exploded, then quite possibly his idealism would not have found expression.
>
> AZETBUR: We are a proud race. We are here because we want to go on
>   being proud.
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): The proposed agenda is as follows. The total evacuation of Kronos has been calculated within the fifty Earth year time span. Phase one, preparation for evacuation...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...discuss the report on Phase two...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...propose we commence within minutes of the preparation...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...and assimilation will continue...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...with the Klingon Empire...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...as I imagine this work will occupy us throughout most of the week, it will be my hope that the delegations can return to the capital to implement the provisions of Phase one no later than the first of next month...
>
> FEDERATION PRESIDENT (OC): ...As you know time is of the essence.

[Undiscovered Country Script](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie6.html)

But in this second script i found these additional lines

> We are gathered here today in high hopes, believing that differing civilizations of good will can work together to overcome intolerance. We believe that with understanding and patience it will be possible to resolve what separates us.
>   We believe that the responsibility
>                                for destiny rests squarely on our
>                                own shoulders...

However this second script, which includes stage directions, is also missing some of the actual dialogue. 
[second script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_VI.htm)

Comment: While this is a good answer, it does not answer the actual question that was asked - is there a **video** of the speech?